# finding records where through multiple assocations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to find multiple records through multiple levels of associations..

I need to iterate through the Orders model with:

Orders where the `Order.cart.line_items` (iterate through line_items)

```
line_item.shop_product.product == vendor_products
```

I am currently doing this with:

```
vendor_products = VendorProduct.where(vendor_id: current_user.id)
vendor_shop_products = ShopProduct.where(product: vendor_products.map { |vp| vp.product_id})
vendor_line_items = LineItem.where(shop_product: vendor_shop_products)
vendor_carts = Cart.where(line_items: vendor_line_items)
vendor_orders = Order.where(cart: vendor_carts)
```

I'm wondering and also assuming there is a much much much much much better way of doing this.  How can i shorten this?

Model:

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop_product, optional: true
  belongs_to :product, optional: true
  belongs_to :cart

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart, optional: true

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :shop_product
  has_one :vendor_product

class ShopProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product, optional: true
  has_one :order

class VendorProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :vendor, :class_name => "User"

class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :order
```

Comment: How're they related?

Comment: Sorry added   sdf fsdfafsd

Comment: And the cart model?

Comment: o geze... added lol

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like this:

```
Order.joins(cart: { line_items: { product: { vendor_product: :vendor } } })
     .where(vendor: { id: current_user.id })
```

Useful readings in the Rails Guides:

- [2.3.1 Equality
  Conditions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#equality-conditions)
- [12.1.3.2 Joining Nested Associations (Multiple
  Level)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-nested-associations-multiple-level)